# bin/magento indexer:reindex gives "no handler found for uri"

Tags: magento2

I'm running this command:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2>php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

But I'm getting an error (at bottom of message):

```
Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:03
Product Flat Data index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:02
Category Flat Data index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Category Products index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Product Categories index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Rule Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:02
Product EAV index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:02
Stock index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Inventory index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Catalog Search index process error during indexation process:
{"error":"no handler found for uri[/magento2_product_1_v3/document/_mappinginclude_type_name=true] and method [PUT]"}
```

Comment: @Mukesh, please try to make more substantive edits. This post had a lot of problems besides unnecessary leading line breaks.

Comment: @GeneralGrievance I will keep it in mind for any edits in future.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you are using Elasticsearch version **8.x** which is not supported by Magento 2 at this time.

So, change Elasticsearch to version 7.x to resolve this issue.

You can read more about system requirement for Elasticsearch from official document: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/system-requirements.html

Answer (score 0):

[Adobe's Comerce Edition System Requirements](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/system-requirements.html) shows that OpenSearch 2.5 is supported.  I was running 2.11 .

#### [on Debian]

`sudo apt list opensearch -a` showed:

```
opensearch/stable,now 2.11.1 amd64 [installed]
opensearch/stable 2.11.0 amd64
opensearch/stable 2.10.0 amd64
opensearch/stable 2.9.0 amd64
opensearch/stable 2.8.0 amd64
opensearch/stable 2.7.0 amd64
opensearch/stable 2.6.0 amd64
opensearch/stable 2.5.0 amd64
```

Perform a downgrade install:
`sudo apt install opensearch=2.5.0`

Next, pin the release (see [Gregor's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/5121/gregor) apt pinning [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/162785/87996))
Create `/etc/apt/preferences.d/opensearch` with the following:

```
Package: opensearch
Pin: version 2.5.*
Pin-Priority: 999
```

It is crude, but opensearch will not start with any forward compatible indexes, ... thus
`sudo rm -rvf /usr/share/opensearch/data/nodes/*`
*(perhaps I should have [removed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30953261/4151626) them before the downgrade, ...

`curl -X DELETE 'http://localhost:9200/_all'`)*

Answer (score 0):

After searching around, I think that I am chasing a false negative error.

`curl -XGET --insecure http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v` generally shows the index in the error message, but with the version number incremented by one.

e.g. the error message will complain about `magento2_product_1_v25` not having a uri, where the `curl ...` command will list `magento2_product_1_v26` as existing.

I couldn't find any issue listing this symptom other than the advice:

> [Wait for changes to be applied](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-knowledge-base/kb/troubleshooting/miscellaneous/live-search-catalog-data-sync.html?lang=en)

So either the search cluster is too fast or too slow, ... regardless, the admin "Index Management" page shows the index as ready.